# How to place text on image in AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

I am new to android game development using andengine.

I am developing a game in which I have to use many different coloured balls.

What i want for improving the game performance is,that i should write random numbers on different balls programmatically?

Is it possible in andengine to add balls as an image and put numbers on top of it programmatically?

Comment: How would this improve game performance?

Comment: Rather than using different balls i can use same ball by attaching different numbers on it as child...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class in AndEngine called `Text`

`Text` objects act like entities and can be attached to a scene or another entity as a child

First you have to create a `Font`

```
Font mFont = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD), 32);
mFont.load();
```

Now create an object of text and add the text to the ball entity

```
Text text = new Text(0,0, font,"1");
ball.attachChild(text);
```

[Here's](http://stuartmct.co.uk/2012/07/16/andengine-creating-and-using-text/) a blog article that may help you more